# django model, a field which required two different fields

Tags: django, django-models

I am building a small web-app. The principle is that a user can register and add a publication (some article which he found in the web) to the database. I wanted to add some infos about the publication like: the title, abstract, date of publication and the authors. The problem is that author/authors could be: **the registered user** (it is possible that the user is one of the author of the article) or unknown person with name, surname, institute and home-page or **mix** the registered user and unknown person/persons. How could I implement that in my model?

Right now I have wrote the user-profile for registered users. It is always good to store some additional infos about the users like e.g. the institute.

For authors of the articles I have **inherit** the class with the **user-profile** class:/ that is not good solution, because unknown author != registered user, but they have the same fields: name, surname, institute, home-page and so on.

I would be very grateful for any tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the publication link to an `Author` instead of `User`, then you'd set up the `Author` class like:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    # etc
```

The idea is that you can generically related the publication to the concept of an author and then allow for the author to be either a registered user (in which case, you'd use the details from the `user` attribute, or an anonymous user (where you would use the other fields on `Author`)

You could then add some utility methods to Author to return the proper data. For example:

```
def get_first_name(self):
    if self.user is not None:
        return self.user.first_name
    else:
        return self.first_name
```

There's a lot more you can do to make it even more seamless, but this is the general idea.